# How to dynamically add multiple items corresponds to single key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to MySQL. I want to create a table with `user_id` and `company_name` and time to time add entries under `company_name`. For example:

```
user_id   |   company_name
mike           Google
               Facebook
steve          nokia
tom            whatsapp
               siemens
```

and when I want to search for a person it should list all the companies a person work for and when required i can delete the company name corresponds to a person.

What could be the best design if want to write in MySQL?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? [Here's some other things](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to think about when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Make `company_name` a null-able column and while deleting, set the column to `NULL` like

```
create table person (user_id int not null,
  company_name varchar(10));
```

You can search your table for a person with `user_id` like

```
select * from person where user_id = 3;
```

While you want to delete the company for a person, do an `UPDATE` like

```
update person set company_name = NULL
where user_id = 3 and company_name = 'Google';
```

(OR)

```
delete from person where user_id = 3 and company_name = 'Google';
```